# Unable to access the fields in inner join

Tags: apex, soql

Can anybody tell me the problem with the code

```
    public class PermissionSetCtrl {
    public List<PermissionSet> qry {get; set;}
    Public List<String> objectlist{get; set;}
    public PermissionSetCtrl(){
        List<string> objlist = new List<String>();
        qry = [SELECT Id, Profile.Name,(Select SObjectType from ObjectPerms) from PermissionSet WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' AND PermissionsRead = true)];                       
         System.debug(qry);
        for(PermissionSet s : qry){
            List<ObjectPermissions> listobj = qry.ObjectPerms;
            //for(ObjectPermissions ob : listobj){ }
            //objectlist.add(s.SObjectType);
        }
    }
}
```

> Error : Variable does not exist: ObjectPerms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping through your `qry` variable which is an array of `PermissionSet`.

If you want to access the `ObjectPerms` list of the `PermissionSet`, you will have to use the current variable in your loop. Which is `s`.

So here's the right code:

```
for(PermissionSet s : qry){
    List<ObjectPermissions> listobj = s.ObjectPerms;
}
```